# Clarification on spells that require the caster to see the target vs those that don't

Tags: dnd-5e, targeting, vision-and-light, line-of-sight

Some spells like [Command](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/command) specify that you need to see your target:

> You speak a one-word command to a creature you can see within range.

Some other spells like [Animate Objects](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/animate-objects) don't specify that you need to see targets:

> Choose up to ten non-magical objects within range that are not being worn or carried.

What are the implications of not requiring the caster to see the target?
For example, in the case of *animated object*, does it imply:

- I can target an invisible object?
- I can target an object beyond my vision range?
- I can target an object behind full cover?

**What are the implications of a spell not requiring the caster to see the target compared to other spells that do?**